# continuous function to continue linear functional in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space infinite dimensional over the complex numbers $\mathbb C$.

Let $S$ be a compact subset of $H$.

Let $V=\overline{\operatorname{span}(S)}$ be the closure of linear span of $S$.

Let $g:S \to \mathbb C$ be a continuous function or rather for each sequence $s_n$ of $S$ such that $s_n \to s_0$ ($H$ metric) then $g(s_n) \to g(s_0)$.

My question is:

> Is it always possible to extend the $g$ function to a 'continue' linear functional on $V$?

Thanks.

Comment: You need a hella lot of other hypotesis: for example, if $v$ and $2v$ are contained in $S$, then you need $g(2v)=2g(v)$, otherwise you can't extend it to a linear function..

Comment: i would like to know if "only" from those hypotesis is possible

Comment: to exstend $g$ to a linear functional on $V$ is Always possible, but my question is about its continuity

Comment: The problem is that it is Not always possible to extend $g$ to a linear function. Take $V=\mathbb C$, $S$ any compact that has at least two points, and the function $g(x)=1$ constant. How do you extend it to a linear map?

Comment: it is always possible because V is the closure of SPAN of S

Comment: @MateyMath Do you assume $g$ to be linear on $S$ from the very beginning?

Comment: NO, $g$ on $S$ is NOT linear, it is just continue on $S$

Comment: $S=\{0\}$, $g(0)=1$. This has no linear extension. It is necessary that $g(\sum_i \lambda_i x_i)=\sum_i\lambda_i g(x_i)$ whenver $x_i$ and $\sum_i \lambda_i x_i$ lie in $S$. With this Hahn Banach gives you the existence of a continuous linear extension.

Comment: @s.harp you have highligheted a hypotesis i didn't say. $S$ is linear independent

Comment: With linearly independent, do you mean that for any finite subset of elements $\{x_1,..,x_n\}\subset S$ that $x_1,..,x_n$ are linearly independent?

Comment: yes, right so. have you any idea. i just don't know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, $S=\{e_1,e_1+\frac1{n^2}e_n\mid n\in\mathbb N,n>1\}$, $g(e_1+\frac1{n^2}e_n)=1+1/n$, $g(e_1)=1$.

You have:

1. $S$ is compact, since any sequence that has an infinite amount of distinct elements must have a subsequence converging to $e_1$.
2. $S$ is linearly independent ($e_i$ is not a linear combination of any of the other $e_j$).
3. $g$ is continuous, since the only accumulation point is $e_1$ so if $e_1+\frac{1}{n_k^2}e_{n_k}\to e_1$ you must have $n_k\to\infty$ and $g(e_1+\frac1{n_k^2}e_{n_k})=1+\frac1{n_k}\to1=g(e_1)$.

However any linear extension $g'$ must have:
$$g'(e_n)=g'\left(n^2(e_1+\frac{1}{n^2}e_n-e_1)\right)=n^2\left(g'(e_1+\frac1{n^2}e_n)-g'(e_1)\right)=n^2+n-n^2=n$$
In other words $\sup_{x\in H,\|x\|≤1}|g'(x)|$ is infinite. This is equivalent to $g'$ not being continuous.

Comment: ok, @s.harp  thanks thanks thanks thanks so much, it is just what i was looking for

Comment: exuse me @s.harp, why $sup$ is infinite? $||e_n||>1$ or i misunderstand?

Comment: @MateyMath $\|e_n\|=1$, $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ can be defined as all square summable sequences and $e_n$ is the sequence that is $1$ in the $n$-th term and $0$ otherwise. Every element of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ is a sum $\sum_n x_n e_n$ which has norm $\sqrt{\sum_n |x_n|^2}$.

Comment: ok @s.harp, i thought you relate $e_n$ to $S$ elements, it is perfect